# iTerm2 Disable Middle Click Paste

Tags: iterm2

How can I disable middle click paste in iTerm 2. I use MiddleClick to enable three finger tap on my MacBook Pro. When in iTerm2 I often hit the touchpad with my wrist which triggers a middle click paste in iTerm2 and a creates mess of code in my VIM. iTerm2's documentation says that the behavior is default but I do not see an option to disable it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

iTerm Preferences / Pointer tab:

Change (or Delete) the Middle button single click action (highlighted line in image below).

[image]

Comment: Highly recommend setting to "Ignore" —otherwise future updates will just use the default.